# Where does the equation for shear stress of a rectangular beam (3/2 V/A) come from?

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis, stresses, beam, shear

I am writing a report and need to reference every equation used. I am using the equation for shear stress in a rectangular beam of

tau = 3/2 * V/A

but am not sure where it came from or what textbook to reference it from! It just seems like common engineering knowledge so I don't know who to put down as the originator of the equation.

Thanks

Comment: Probably any book by Timoshenko...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the following link

[Advanced Mechanics of Materials and Applied Elasticity, 6th Edition](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2982118&seqNum=7) by By Ansel C. Ugural and Saul K. Fenster.

You can find this derivation in literally every handbook of mechanics of materials.

Comment: Thank you so so much!